# Initialise Google Motion chart with log axis

Tags: java, gwt

I am not sure if this is the place to ask, but I saw another question about google motion charts here, so here I go...

I have javascript that creates a chart, I don't initialise a state, but I read [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#Motion_Chart_initial_state) how to do that.

My question is, how do I start the chart with logaritmic axis? I haven't found any documentation about this. Perhaps I have overlooked something. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Follow these steps:

1. Open a working chart and set the settings that you'd like to capture. Settings you can specify include opacity levels, zooming, and log vs linear scaling.
2. Open the Settings panel by clicking the wrench symbol in the lower right corner of the chart.
3. Click the Advanced link in the lower left corner to add the Advanced panel to the set.
   Expand the Advanced panel and copy the contents of the State text box to your clipboard. (Note: instead of using the menu, described in steps 2—4, you could insert a button on your page that calls getState() and displays the current state in a message box.)
4. Assign the state string that you copied in the previous step to the "state" options parameter in your code, as shown here. When passed into the draw() method, the chart will be initialized to the state specified on startup.

I think the log/lin refers to the parameter xAxisOption: 2.

Somewhere in the beginning of the code, paste this (and replace the state with your clipboard content):

```
  var options = {};
  options['state'] ='{"duration":{"multiplier":1,"timeUnit":"D"},"yLambda":0,"yZoomedIn":false,"showTrails":true,"dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"xAxisOption":"2","iconKeySettings":[],"xZoomedDataMin":18.75546,"time":"1985-02-12","colorOption":"4","xZoomedDataMax":1133.55129,"orderedByX":false,"orderedByY":false,"xLambda":0,"playDuration":15000,"iconType":"BUBBLE","yAxisOption":"3","yZoomedDataMin":-32.736,"xZoomedIn":false,"yZoomedDataMax":-1.166,"sizeOption":"5"};';
```

Then comes the chart data and in the end:

```
options['width'] = 760;
options['height'] = 480;

chart.draw(data, options);
```